# What does the star in the field_name input mean in the Python str.format() docs?

Tags: python

In "6.1.3. Format String Syntax" in the Python 3.5.2 docs, the `field_name` for the replacement field grammar for `str.format()` is written like this:

```
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
```

What does the star at the very right mean? I can guess that I can get an object's attribute with `arg_name.attribute` or element with `arg_name[element_index]`, but I don't know if that extra star means I can do more with the object. I'm guessing it means that `.attribute_name` and `[element_index]` are optional, but I thought the parentheses already implied that.

Comment: I'm guessing `*` means that `("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")` can repeat any number of times, including 0.

Comment: @vaultah I think you're right. Do you know where in the docs the `*` is described? I remember seeing it somewhere in there, I don't know where exactly though.

Comment: @vaultah you are right.

Comment: ya, @vaultah's right. I found the notation for `*` in 1.2. Notation: "A star (*) means zero or more repetitions of the preceding item." I can accept your comment as an answer then.

Comment: @DragonautX, you can add and accept your own answer if Vaultah does not provide one.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok, thanks. Someone already added a linked answer though, so I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python Language Reference, section 1.2.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation) says:

> The descriptions of lexical analysis and syntax use a modified BNF
>   grammar notation. This uses the following style of definition:
>
> ```
> name      ::=  lc_letter (lc_letter | "_")*
> lc_letter ::=  "a"..."z"
> ```
>
> The first line says that a `name` is an `lc_letter` followed by a sequence
>   of zero or more `lc_letter`s and underscores. An `lc_letter` in turn is
>   any of the single characters `'a'` through `'z'`. (This rule is actually
>   adhered to for the names defined in lexical and grammar rules in this
>   document.)
>
> Each rule begins with a name (which is the name defined by the rule) and `::=`. A vertical bar (`|`) is used to separate alternatives; it is the least binding operator in this notation. A star (`*`) means zero or more repetitions of the preceding item; likewise, a plus (`+`) means one or more repetitions, and a phrase enclosed in square brackets (`[ ]`) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional). The `*` and `+` operators bind as tightly as possible; parentheses are used for grouping. Literal strings are enclosed in quotes. White space is only meaningful to separate tokens. Rules are normally contained on a single line; rules with many alternatives may be formatted alternatively with each line after the first beginning with a vertical bar.

So, asterisk `*` means, as expected, zero or more repetitions of the preceding group.

Comment: I think you meant to copy the next paragraph too which talked about the star, but I'll still accept your answer since you gave a link. Thanks.

Comment: @DragonautX Right, I added that to the answer.